# make something of a color of visited links with css?

Tags: css

I'm trying to show the user an example of how visited link would look like but it proved to be near impossible with current level of CSS technological advancement...

The best solution found so far was to use `href=""` but sadly it doesn't always produce a visited link, it could just fail and show up as unvisited as well with the regular link color.

is something like `color: --color_of_visited_links` not possible??

+I don't know know the color of visited so I can't hardcode it

++the text color of what I want to make have the color of visited links is NOT actually a visited link so it originally does not have that color.

Comment: _"no, I can't possible know the color of visited links to hardcode it since the user himself chooses it"_ - but that user choice must make its way into your code somehow, otherwise how would you _apply_ their choice in the first place?

Comment: Please explain why the standard `:visited` does not work for you here ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited

Comment: That question and answers were made more than 13 years ago...  perhaps something changed since then...

the hack with `history.replaceState` actually works... but the downside for it is that it clutters user visited history with the fake links we create just to make something point-href to it to look visited

Answer (score 0):

You can easily target visited links with the `:visited` pseudo selector.

```
a:visited {
   color: var(--color)
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.php?filename=trycss_sel_visited

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you use an anchor tag `<a>` for your link. Then you can do this:

```
a:visited {
  color: --color_of_visited_links
}
```

More on pseudo classes here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes